# Ag-grid-enterprise: TypeError: details.rootNode.updateHasChildren is not function

Tags: angular, ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

[image]

I am using Angular 9 and I have installed all necessary ag-grid packages.

Package.json:

```
"ag-grid-angular": "^23.1.1",
"ag-grid-community": "^23.1.1",
"ag-grid-enterprise": "^24.0.0"
```

For ag-grid-enterprise i have added license and which i have imported into main.ts

main.ts

```
// other imports...

import {LicenseManager} from "ag-grid-enterprise";
LicenseManager.setLicenseKey("license key");

// bootstrap your angular application. ie: platformBrowser().bootstrapModuleFactory(..)
```

And imported ag-grid-enterprise in the app module and imported styles into style.scss too

```
import 'ag-grid-enterprise';

import 'ag-grid-community/dist/styles/ag-grid.css';
import 'ag-grid-community/dist/styles/ag-theme-alpine.css';
```

I have tried to display RowGrouping table and simple table also. Please find some sample code below
Html:

```
<ag-grid-angular
style="width: 500px; height: 150px;"
class="ag-theme-alpine"
[rowData]="rowData"
[columnDefs]="columnDefs">
</ag-grid-angular>
```

ts:

```
   import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.scss' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {

    columnDefs = [
        {field: 'make' },
        {field: 'model' },
        {field: 'price'}
    ];

    rowData = [
        { make: 'Toyota', model: 'Celica', price: 35000 },
        { make: 'Ford', model: 'Mondeo', price: 32000 },
        { make: 'Porsche', model: 'Boxter', price: 72000 }
    ];

}
```

I'm getting  below error and table not loading when launch the application into browser. Also Find the screenshot for reference.

```
TypeError: details.rootNode.updateHasChildren is not function
```

Comment: why you are importing community and enterprise versions both?

Answer (score 0):

All the code you've sent looks fine, the only thing that does look strange is your `package.json`.

You should be keeping all the versions consistent, i.e. if using v23.1.1, then `ag-grid-commmunity`, `ag-grid-enterprise`, and `ag-grid-angular` must all be v23.1.1.

I would change the package.json to this, and see if it helps:

```
"ag-grid-angular": "^23.1.1",
"ag-grid-community": "^23.1.1",
"ag-grid-enterprise": "^23.1.1"
```